# WebView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm just a beginner in Android and I started to deal with webViews. Indeed, I have created two button that will take me into two different activities but when I run the application the webview doesn't load the page which is Google.com. I already inserted the internet permission.

Here, I did onClick method as an attribute in the button that when I click on it has to go to the twitter website. I put it in a different activity class.

```
 public void listen(View v)
 {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), onemore.class);
    startActivity(intent);          
 }
```

this is the activity class

```
package com.example.aboutme;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;


    public class onemore extends Activity 
    {
          private String uagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; 
                                   Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 
                                   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile 
                                   Safari/530.17";

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.twomore);
            displayTweets();
        }


        private void displayTweets() 
        {
            WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(uagent); 

            mWebView.loadUrl("http://mobile.twitter.com/");
        }

    }
```

the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView1" 

    />
```

the manifest xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aboutme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />



    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
     <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    </application>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your manifest? I did not see it, but maybe you changed the name for the SO question from ActivityTwo.

> activity android:name=".onemore">

Your code worked fine when I ran it. What was the error message you were getting?